# I'm using React Native html render, React Native webview all of them throw the same error. Dimension is not define?

Tags: react-native, webview

I'm using React Native html render, React Native webview all of them throw the same error. Dimension is not define? How can I solve that error? I have import dimension and so on.

Here is my code

```
 <Image source={{uri: _embedded['wp:featuredmedia'][0].media_details.sizes.medium_large.source_url}} />
        <Text>{title.rendered}</Text>
        <Text>{content.rendered}</Text>
        <WebView style={styles.webView}
source={{uri: content.rendered}}
javaScriptEnabled={true}
domStorageEnabled={true}
startInLoadingState={true}
```

Comment: Can you clarify your question better. Pleas read how to ask a quation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: sure. Im using https://github.com/archriss/react-native-render-html
to render html from json object. but it thrown error Dimension is not define. is there anything wrong with that beside import it like usual
i have follow instruction 
 <ScrollView style={{ flex: 1 }}>
                <HTML html={htmlContent} imagesMaxWidth={Dimensions.get('window').width} />
            </ScrollView>
import Dimension from 'react-native';

i have no clue

Comment: Please add that to your question by editing it.